# Como alterar a largura de um navbar bootstrap nativo?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-blade, nav-bar

Bom dia.

Eu preciso alterar a largura de um navbar nativo. Simplesmente peguei no site boostrap.com e colei no meu template.blade.php mas está ocupando a tela toda e preciso reduzir sua largura. Tem como?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```css
.navbar.custom {
  width: 50%;  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom">
```

No seu `nav` adicione a classe custom, depois no seu css adicione:

```
.navbar.custom {
  width: 50%;  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Altere o valor de `width` para encontrar o tamanho ideal!

Comment: Não alterou. Eu fiz corretamente?

No meu NAV
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom">

Comment: No meu CSS
/*
Menu
*/
.navbar.custom {
  width: 50%;  
  margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: tá certinho, esse css tá sendo carregado na página? tenta inspecionar o elemento `nav` pra ver se tá relacionando direitinho